# TypeORM: QueryFailedError: relation does not exist

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I need a little help with migration. I'm trying to seed DB using migration. But I get an error "QueryFailedError: relation "account" does not exist". I think it's just typical newbie mistake. So please check my code:

**account.entity.ts**

```ts
import { BeforeInsert, Column, Entity, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { AbstractEntity } from '../../common/abstract.entity';
import { SourceEntity } from '../source/source.entity';
import { UtilsService } from '../../shared/services/utils.service';

@Entity({ name: 'account' })
export class AccountEntity extends AbstractEntity {
  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  password: string;

  @OneToMany(() => SourceEntity, (source) => source.account, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  sources: SourceEntity[];

  @BeforeInsert()
  async setPassword() {
    this.password = UtilsService.generateHash(this.password);
  }
}
```

**seed-data.migration.ts**

```ts
import { getCustomRepository, MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';
import { AccountRepository } from '../modules/account/account.repository';
import { SourceRepository } from '../modules/source/source.repository';

type DataType = {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  sources: { username: string }[];
};

export class SeedData1617243952346 implements MigrationInterface {
  private data: DataType[] = [
    {
      username: 'test',
      password: 'password',
      sources: [
        { username: 'some_test' },
        { username: 'okey_test' },
        { username: 'super_test' },
      ],
    },
    {
      username: 'account',
      password: 'password',
      sources: [
        { username: 'some_account' },
        { username: 'okey_account' },
        { username: 'super_account' },
      ],
    },
  ];

  public async up(): Promise<void> {
    await Promise.all(
      this.data.map(async (item) => {
        const accountRepository = getCustomRepository(AccountRepository);
        const accountEntity = accountRepository.create();
        accountEntity.username = item.username;
        accountEntity.password = item.password;

        const sourceRepository = getCustomRepository(SourceRepository);
        const sources = [];

        await Promise.all(
          item.sources.map(async (sourceItem) => {
            const sourceEntity = sourceRepository.create();
            sourceEntity.username = sourceItem.username;

            sources.push(sourceEntity);
          }),
        );

        accountEntity.sources = sources;
        const account = await accountRepository.save(accountEntity);
        console.log('Account created:', account.id);
      }),
    );
  }

  public async down(): Promise<void> {
    await Promise.all(
      this.data.map(async (item) => {
        const sourceRepository = getCustomRepository(SourceRepository);
        const accountRepository = getCustomRepository(AccountRepository);

        const account = await accountRepository.findOne({
          where: { username: item.username },
        });
        if (account) {
          await Promise.all(
            item.sources.map(async (src) => {
              const source = await sourceRepository.findOne({
                where: { username: src.username },
              });
              if (source) {
                await sourceRepository.delete(source);
              }
            }),
          );

          await accountRepository.delete(account);
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

**source.entity.ts**

```ts
import { Column, Entity, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { AbstractEntity } from '../../common/abstract.entity';
import { AccountEntity } from '../account/account.entity';

@Entity({ name: 'source' })
export class SourceEntity extends AbstractEntity {
  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  overrideCaption: boolean;

  @ManyToOne(() => AccountEntity, (account) => account.sources)
  account: AccountEntity;
}
```

**Error:**

```sh
Error during migration run:
QueryFailedError: relation "account" does not exist
    at new QueryFailedError (/home/wiha/dev/own/instahub/src/error/QueryFailedError.ts:9:9)
    at PostgresQueryRunner.<anonymous> (/home/wiha/dev/own/instahub/src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:228:19)
    at step (/home/wiha/dev/own/instahub/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:143:27)
    at Object.throw (/home/wiha/dev/own/instahub/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:124:57)
    at rejected (/home/wiha/dev/own/instahub/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:115:69)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  length: 106,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '13',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'parse_relation.c',
  line: '1191',
  routine: 'parserOpenTable',
  query: 'INSERT INTO "account"("id", "created_at", "updated_at", "username", "password") VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, $1, $2) RETURNING "id", "created_at", "updated_at"',
  parameters: [
    'test',
    '$2b$10$iB6yb3D8e6iGmKoVAJ7eYeYfoItclw5lcVXqauPf9VH94DlDrbuSa'
  ]
}
```

Tables are created in another migration

DB: PostgreSQL 12.6
Node: 14.0.0
TypeORM: 0.2.32
@nestjs/typeorm: 7.1.5

Comment: how do you initialize your db?

Comment: @shusson via TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync

Comment: can you show more code? TypeORM can create the schema for you, but it depends how you initialize the TypeORM connection.

Comment: @shusson check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/qWici/023b7f0404ad3d8c84fd73436eff1541)

Comment: you need to double check your entities list includes the account entity. https://gist.github.com/qWici/023b7f0404ad3d8c84fd73436eff1541#file-config-service-ts-L40

Comment: @shusson I have next struct - [screenshot on Imgur](https://imgur.com/a/xnirDnw). So I think it's works fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When creating a connection through TypeORM you need to pass `synchronize: true,` if you want TypeORM to create schema for you. Alternativly you can manually run sync using the CLI with `schema:sync` command.

More
e.g :

```
createConnection({
    type: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    username: "root",
    password: "admin",
    database: "test",
    entities: [
        Photo
    ],

// ---
    synchronize: true,
// ---
    logging: false
```

From the [docs](https://typeorm.io/#/connection-options)

> synchronize - Indicates if database schema should be auto created on every application launch. Be careful with this option and don't use this in production - otherwise you can lose production data. This option is useful during debug and development. As an alternative to it, you can use CLI and run schema:sync command. Note that for MongoDB database it does not create schema, because MongoDB is schemaless. Instead, it syncs just by creating indices.

Comment: Mark this answer as correct. But what I actually done:  
1. Remove migration for creating tables for entities  
2. Set **synchronize** to true  
3. Recreate DB
4. Run typeorm schema:sync
5. Run migration

Answer (score 7):

Just in case I help someone, my issue was not specifying the schema in the Entity

```
@Entity({ name: 'account', schema: 'companydbo' })
```

Comment: +1 to this because its really not clear why it works the first time (it assumes the 'public' schema in postgres when creating the table, which is what i would expect), but not the second time (on a rerun of sync when the table already exists). fixed my problem, don't know why dont care why, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying something similar. I put the data source [countries] in a JSON file and this work for me:
`

```
// In a prev migration the countries table was created
// Then in a new migration

export class SeedCountriesTable1616610473154 implements MigrationInterface {
    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        // Trying to commit last transcaction
        await queryRunner.commitTransaction().then(async () => {
            // Seeding database
            // Then try to start another one
            await queryRunner.startTransaction().then(async () => {
                await getRepository('countries').save(countries);
            });
        });
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
    public async down(): Promise<void> {}
}
```

`
I hope can help you.

Comment: Great job, this is exactly what we needed !

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I used double-quotes around my value instead of single quotes. For example:

WRONG:

```
private static async getProducts(): Promise<Product[]> {
  return await getRepository(Product)
    .createQueryBuilder('product')
    .where('product.source = "noobie"') // <---- DOUBLE QUOTES = BAD!!!
    .getMany();
}
```

RIGHT:

```
private static async getProducts(): Promise<Product[]> {
  return await getRepository(Product)
    .createQueryBuilder('product')
    .where("product.source = 'noobie'") // <---- SINGLE QUOTES!!!
    .getMany();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in NestJS while doing e2e tests. The Jest runs tests in different files concurrently. This is a problem when you use the same database instance for all tests, because different tests will edit or tear down the database concurrently.

To fix that, I appended `--runInBand` option in `jest` command for `test:e2e` script in `package.json` file:

```
"test:e2e": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json --runInBand"
```

This will make the tests run serially one file at a time. Using this option also surprisingly reduced the time taken to complete the tests.

There are also other alternatives to make the tests run concurrently but you have to use multiple database instances for multiple files and the setup is a bit more involved.

Answer (score -1):

just add `migrationsTransactionMode: 'each'` in your datasource :)